# Animate div background-position (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I would like to animate the background of my div. The background position should move from left-top, to right-bottom. For some reason, nothing happens. And I have no idea why

```
.test {
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, green 0%, blue 100%);
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    animation: moving-gradient 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes moving-gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: left top;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: right bottom;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uLedmk5k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of moving the background image, have you tried moving the element?

`translate` is a very efficient and smooth (because of its anti-aliasing) way to move elements on screen, plus you can use percentages with ease.

An [example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MangopearUK/24xwynr0/1/) might help explain?

Although I may have completely misunderstood what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use fixed values for your background animation to work  :

```
@keyframes moving-gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0,0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 200px 250px, 200px 250px;
    }
}
```

So you will have to set a fixed width to your element too :

```
.test {
     width: 200px;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLedmk5k/4/)

#### Edit from comments

if you set your width to viewport units it will work too :

```
.test {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 250px;
```

and in animation

```
100% {
    background-position: 50vw 250px, 50vw 250px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLedmk5k/6/)
I'm not sure why but looking to `computed` tab in Firebug shows that viewport units are actually interpreted as fixed `px` values

Comment: But the percentage values doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Sorry bad link… yes there is a strange behaviour with percents where if you set it to very large values it will just move a little bit… If you do set your element width to 50vwand your animation height to same fixed values, it will work : http://jsfiddle.net/uLedmk5k/6

Comment: I'm not sure why but looking to `computed` tab in Firebug shows that viewport units are actually interpreted as fixed `px` values

Answer (score 1):

A stupid way but works
http://jsfiddle.net/uLedmk5k/9/

Use 4 div and translate

HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="bg"></div><div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: moving-gradient 1s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: moving-gradient 1s infinite;
}

.bg::after, .bg::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, green 0%, blue 100%);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@keyframes moving-gradient {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving-gradient {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}
```